# How does python deal with this inheritance issue?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('I am A')


class B(A):
    def b(self):
        print('I am B.b')


class C(A):
    def c(self):
        x.b()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = B()
    y = C()
    y.c()
```

How does it work when it comes to 'y.c() '?
In C.c(), how can the instance x be called without instantiation before?
Thanks a lot, if someone can help.

Comment: did you mean `self.b()`?  (`x` is a global variable instantiated in your `"__main__"` clause).

Comment: `x` is a global variable. You created it outside of any function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot. In your case, it just happens that when you call `x.b()` there is *a global* variable that happens to be named `x` have type `B`. It *has been initialized* at the previous line, with `x = B()`.

This code depends on external variables, and will fail in general. If you want to call the objects own method, use `self.b()` instead.